# how to redirect non-www to www on aws lightsail using route 53

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, http-redirect, amazon-lightsail

I tried redirection via .htaccess. it seems the .htaccess file is not read or processed by AWS-lightsail and used the redirection plugin in WordPress for redirection. it is also not working. www and non-www both are accessible that is not google for google analytics. If there is any solution to fix this. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using bitnami (common for setting up WordPress with AWS):

You can edit httpd-app.conf to enable .htaccess overrides in directories:

```
nano /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf
```

Under:

```
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs">
```

Change:

```
AllowOverride None
```

to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Alternatively, you can accomplish the redirect by editing the same httpd-app.conf file without enabling .htaccess. The following would be added in place of, or in addition too, the change above:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

The above has two conditions 1) if HTTPS is off OR 2) if the host includes www, redirect to https://example.com, maintain the URL, and return a 301 response.

Also don't forget to restart apache by running the following command.

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Great! How would this be rewritten to redirect from domain.tld to www.domain.tld?